# How to get ILO IP address without a monitor?

Tags: linux, ip, hp, remote-access, ilo

I have a microserver gen8, that i just changed its location, now it's not connecting automatically to the internet.

And to debug it i want to connect to ILO which is link up now but i don't remember the IP address nor i have a monitor nearby to connect it directly to the server.

How can i get ILO address so i can connect to the server? if it's not possible then maybe reset the ip to a default one ?

PS: I have OSX system to as my PC to connect to the server.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another solution, that does not depend on having (proprietary) tools from HP installed on your system, is to use the vendor-neutral ipmi utilities.

You can install the package called ipmitool on the linux system you have installed on your system (it is found in the repositories of Debian, Ubuntu, Centos, Fedora, Redhat,....)

You can then type

```
ipmitool lan print
```

and you'd get all network information possible from the ipmi (here iLO) module.

Source: https://setaoffice.com/2014/01/10/discover-hp-ilo-ip-address-in-linux/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your Linux system is functioning, you can install the iLO online configuration utility (`hponcfg`). You can use it to get the iLO's configuration or reconfigure it. The configuration is in XML format.

You didn't mention which flavor of Linux you're using, but HPE makes `hponcfg` packages available for numerous distributions in their [Software Delivery Repository](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/). Packages for RHEL and SLES are in their [Service Pack for Proliant (SPP)](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/spp) repository, and packages for Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, and others are in the [Management Component Pack (MCP)](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp) repo. They're set up as native repositories, so you can add them to your system and install or update them via `yum`, `apt-get`, etc.

Alternatively, you can browse the [top-level repository](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/) directory and download packages manually if you want to.

Comment: My system is OS X, on the server there's CentOS but i don't have access to it now because internet is down and can't SSH to it.

Comment: In that case, @natxoasenjo's answer will probably be more useful to you, since it doesn't require that CentOS be functional.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work and i have to get a monitor :(

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two options:

- check your dhcp server logs, you might have the ilo nic on dhcp;
- try scanning your network with `nmap -n -P0 -sS -p 17988 -oG - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx` where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx is the representation of your network/netmask

The switches mean:

```
-n no dns resolution
-P0 is now -Pn: no ping
-sS: tcp syn scan
-p 17988: only scan for port 17988
-oG - : is now deprecated, used for formatting (I think, it's been a while)
```

The last argument is the network segment you wish to scan.

Comment: i tried running this on my that is connected to the same network as the server but it didn't catch anything. i put 192.168.0.1/24 , please correct me if i'm mistaked, thank you

Comment: that is not a correct network address, I think you want to try 192.168.0.0/24 (if your hosts have ips like 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, etc). You can also try finding live hosts in the network using `nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24`

Comment: But please keep in mind, i don't have access to the system on the server, i'm doing this from my laptop which is connected to the network, it's fine ?

Comment: it's not finding anything but my laptop and the router :( any ideas ?

Comment: if you find nothing, then maybe it's time to get yourself a monitor (and a keyboard)

Comment: It's working for me, but could you please explain the `nmap` command you have used here.